# looping query query returning more records than needed

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Please help with this query. It should only return less than 3000 records but its returning over 4M. It needs to show all duplicate records... All the info are on the same table VENDFIl, so I used a self join but it seems to be looping...
The query:

```
SELECT A.FEDTID, B.VENDOR, C.NPI_NUMBER
FROM VENDFIL A, VENDFIL B, VENDFIL C
GROUP BY A.FEDTID, B.VENDOR
```

Thanks...

Comment: Provide more information about your tables.

Comment: all the info are on one table ...vendfil...its an alphanumeric table the query work its just returning more info than needed which exceed the table's property

Comment: You didn't use a self-join, you are using a `CROSS JOIN` and are creating a Cartesian product.  If you need to self-join then you actually need to join the tables on a specific column.

Comment: Eliminate the joins entirely.  `SELECT  A.Fedtid, A.Vendor, A.NPI_NUMBER FROM VENDFIL A ORDER BY A.FEDTID, A.VENDOR` each JOIN is causing the multiple records.  So if Vendfil has 100 Records you're generating  100*100*100.  If you just select from vendfil, you'll have 100 records.  If you joined on criteria, the number of records generated will be equal to the number of matching records 1*2*2+X*y*Z where xyz are number of related records in each table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are making tripple `cross join`.
If you want to join a table with it self you need to define the condition.

if you want to show duplicate records you don't need a join

```
SELECT fedtid, vendor, npi_number, COUNT(1) cnt
    FROM vendfil
GROUP BY fedtid, vendor, npi_number
  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

for showing duplicated records and repeat them as much as they repeated use this query

```
Select * from vendfil
where Exists(
   Select * from (SELECT fedtid, vendor, npi_number, COUNT(1) cnt
                  FROM vendfil
                  GROUP BY fedtid, vendor, npi_number
                  HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) t
   where t.fedtid = vendfil.fedtid and t.vendor = vendfil.vendor and t.npi_number = vendfil.npi_number
)
```

Comment: good one. It shows the dupes now, but is there a way to group the dupes together....

Comment: what do you mean by `group dupes together`

Comment: updating your question and showing your desired result might help

Comment: the duplicate records in the output to be arranged or bunch together

Comment: Do you mean showing all the duplicate records and repeat them as many as they are exist?

Comment: yes.. all the duplicate records and repeat them as many as they are exist

Answer (score 0):

why do you need a self join? use a having clause

```
  SELECT fedtid, vendor, npi_number, COUNT(*)
    FROM vendfil
GROUP BY fedtid, vendor, npi_number
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
```